# WTS) Geometric distribution is the only discrete memoryless distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I want to prove that if a discrete distribution is memoryless, the distribution must be geometric. I read up on older posts asking this question, but I couldn't follow any of the answers. How should I get started on this proof? Any hints or steps would be appreciated.

Comment: First you have to decide the form of your memorylessness property with $\gt$ or $\ge$ which affects whether you have $\mathbb P(X=1)=p$ or $\mathbb P(X=0)=p$.  Then you show that $\mathbb P(X=n+1)=(1-p)\mathbb P(X=n)$

Comment: Which part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/923009/321264) post could you not follow? Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/392000/321264) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1830327/321264). There are countless posts on this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538123/321264

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's prove that the geometric is memoryless :

$$\mathbb{P}[X > n+k \mid X > k] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X > n+k,X > k]}{\mathbb{P}[X > k]} = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X > n+k]}{\mathbb{P}[X > k]} = $$

$$ = \frac{(1-p)^{n+k}}{(1-p)^{k}} = \mathbb{P}[X>n]$$

Viceversa, if we have a distribution such that for every $k$

$\mathbb{P}[X>n+k \mid X > k] = \mathbb{P}[X > n]$ holds,it must holds for $k=1$.

In first place we can notice that $$\mathbb{P}[X>n] = \mathbb{P}[X>n+1 \mid X > 1] = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X > n+1]}{\mathbb{P}[X>1]}$$

If we denote with $p:= 1 - \mathbb{P}[X>1]$ we have :

$$\mathbb{P}[X>n+1] = \mathbb{P}[X>n]\mathbb{P}[X>1] =$$

$$(1-p)\mathbb{P}[X>n] = (1-p)^{2}\mathbb{P}[X>n-1] \cdots = (1-p)^{n+1}$$

Which gives :

$$\mathbb{P}[X = n] = \mathbb{P}[X>n-1] - \mathbb{P}[X>n] = (1-p)^{n-1}-(1-p)^{n} = p(1-p)^{n-1}$$

Hence, the geometric distribution.

Let me know if there are flaws or different notation which you are not comfortable with.

Comment: This is beautiful, and everything is clear. Thank you so much!